# Salesforce SOAP Exception

Tags: soap, workflowoutboundmessage

I am sending the response below to Salesforce after having successfully processed in my BPM, however, Salesforce is giving me the following response:

“org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize”

```
2014-10-09 09:53:40 EDT [ISC.0088.0019I] SOAP Response:
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body
ser-root:getSFDCMessagesResponse xmlns:ser-root="http://devbpm3905/AtSalesForceServices/webservice/provider/closeSFDCChildCase1_/connectors/receiveSFDCMessage" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <notificationsResponse>
    <Ack>true</Ack>
  </notificationsResponse>
</ser-root:getSFDCMessagesResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Would you know if anything additional or different needs to be passed in my response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected payload is structured like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
      <Ack>true</Ack>
    </notificationsResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The difference is that your payload includes this child element: `<ser-root:getSFDCMessagesResponse` which is why the parser complains about an unexpected child. Remove it and you should be fine.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ser-root:getSFDCMessagesResponse
            xmlns:ser-root="http://devbpm3905/AtSalesForceServices/webservice/provider/closeSFDCChildCase1_/connectors/receiveSFDCMessage"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <notificationsResponse>
                <Ack>true</Ack>
            </notificationsResponse>
        </ser-root:getSFDCMessagesResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```